# Write Excel values to datatable

Tags: c#, excel

I have Excel file in format

`ValueX ValueY ValueX ValueY ValueX ValueY ValueX ValueY ValueX ValueY ValueX ValueY ... (column1 - ValueX, column2 - ValueY)`

After reading Excel (which works good) I need to create datatable with next format:

`value1X value2X value3X value4X value5X value6X ... - columns`

`value1Y value2Y value3Y value4Y value5Y value6Y ... - rows`

Next code gets columns (first for loop) and it woks fine, but next code should get row, but it only gets one (first value - value1Y) (second for loop):

```
        for (int i = 4; i < 38; i++)
        {
            excelRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1];
            string strValue = excelRange.Text.ToString();
            dataTable.Columns.Add(strValue, System.Type.GetType("System.String"));

        }

        for (int i = 4; i < 38; i++)
        {
            dataRow = dataSet.Tables["GeneralInfo"].NewRow();
            excelRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2];
            excelCheckRange = (Excel.Range)excelWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1];
            string strValue = excelRange.Text.ToString();
            string strValue1 = excelCheckRange.Text.ToString();
            dataRow[strValue1] = strValue;
            dataSet.Tables["GeneralInfo"].Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
```

Comment: second for loop is to get one row or multiple rows?

Comment: only one row (thats why there is [i, 2]...

Comment: Excel sheet is in format ValueX A4:A37, ValueY B4:B37... what i actually need is to transform values from A column in Excel to columns in datatable, and values from B column in Excel to row